# How to concatenate the result set of multiple queries in orientDB without using UNIONALL

Tags: sql, database, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a student node which has the following edges:

Student - HasLocation - Location (HasLocation Edge from Student node to Location node)

```
Student-HasSchool-School 
Student - HasUniversity - University
Student - HasInterest -Interest 
Student -LookingFor - Type (Full Time or Intership)
```

Similarly, we have Companies providing internships which have the following edges:

```
Company - HasLocation - Location
Company - HasInterest - Interest
Commpany - HasType - Type (Full Time or Intership)
```

Now I want to write a query to match all the conditions i.e. the location, type interest etc. and then want to remove type and have the conditions as location, interest, etc.

As of for now I have written seperate queries for them and then take UNIONALL and then take the distinct of them. In order to achieve time efficiency, I have not been able to apply pagination either.

Is their any better way to achieve this in OrientDB?

Note: I am not using the concept of temp variable assigning it the number of conditions matching and then ordering by it as it will take immense amount of time by traversing to each and every node and then assigning a temp value.

Comment: Can you show us the queries you've tried so far for a better understanding?

Comment: Hi Harsh Butani, which version of orientdb are you using?